# python -- how to return button position (x,y)

Tags: python, popup, tkinter

how to return button position

```
import tkinter as tk
def do_popup():
    root.menu.post(??,??)
root = tk.Tk()
root.btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="POPUP", command=do_popup)
root.btn1.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.menu = tk.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
root.menu.add_command(label="a")
root.menu.add_command(label="b")
root.menu.add_command(label="c")
```

how to get the POPUP button's x and y ???

Comment: you might be looking for `winfo_geometry()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Tkinter's `winfo_rootx()` and `winfo_rooty()` methods, which return pixel coordinates relative to the screen's upper left corner.

```
def do_popup():
    x, y = root.btn1.winfo_rootx(), root.btn1.winfo_rooty()
    print (x, y)
```

More: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rootx-method